# Multiple Visual Studio Projects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to move all of my non Unity-specific code into classes which don't inherit from `MonoBehaviour`, similar to [this](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/03/unit-testing-part-2-unit-testing-monobehaviours/).  I created a separate Visual Studio project called `Models` for all of my non-`MonoBehaviour` classes, and I added that project to the Visual Studio solution.  However, I can't add a reference to my `Models` project to my Unity project through Visual Studio (the Add Reference button isn't there when I click on the Unity project, and I've read that Unity automatically rebuilds its Visual Studio project anyway, so any added references would be lost), so I set the output location of my `Models` .dll to the Assets folder in Unity and I added that .dll to my Project view in Unity.  That's all working.  The problem is that whenever I rebuild my `Models` project, the Unity project in Visual Studio doesn't seem to pick up the changes, so I have to delete the .dll from the Project view in Unity and re-add it every time I make any changes to the `Models` project.

Is there a way to have Visual Studio automatically see the changes to my `Models` .dll, or is there a better way to go about having my Unity project reference another Visual Studio project?

Comment: sophisticated question!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html

Comment: Yes, that's working.  Thank you.  I thought that's more-or-less what I had done at first, but I must have made a mistake.  When I did it at first, I manually dropped the .dll into my Assets folder, and then just had Visual Studio keep recreating it.  When I tried it again, I didn't manually put any files into the Assets folder, and instead I and pointed the .dll's output directory there right off the bat.  Maybe that was the difference, or maybe I made a mistake in my output path initially.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried researching this for you, and the closest thing i could find so far is this: http://devleader.ca/2015/02/08/multiple-c-projects-unity-3d-solution/

It details how to adopt unity and visual studio to work well and sync up correctly without rebuilding/running/other crazy things to get the projects working together.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank for the answer.  Those are more-or-less the steps that I followed and I have it working now.  Interestingly, I didn't have to do the part about creating the junction (even though that post says the junction is the solution to the problem I was having).  I pointed the .dll project's output directory to the Unity Assets folder without manually moving the .dll, and it's working now.

Comment: Ah. That is interesting. It's good to know what for future use. Thank you :)

Comment: This is a link-only answer susceptible to link-rot. I'm not sure that editing it to include enough information to be an actual answer is the way to go either though.

It apparently has issues with Unity 5.2 and newer, and even the link points to a newer Unity feature (since Dec 2017) [Assembly Definition files](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) which may be a better candidate for a modern answer to this question.